# Tag suggestion: [word-square]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

It would help clarify questions like these:
[Some four word puzzles (and possible bounty)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17907/some-four-word-puzzles-and-possible-bounty)
[Largest word-square puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17908/largest-four-word-puzzle)

And it would help users find puzzles like these:
[Four-words (----||||)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/four-words)
[Another Four-words (----||||)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16887/another-four-words)
[Five-words (-----|||||)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15341/five-words)
[Another Six-words (------||||||)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15407/another-six-words)

Edit:  [word-square article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square)

Comment: I think this is a great idea! You have the power, you can make it happen

Comment: Ohh, I thought it had to be approved.

Comment: It can be friendly to ask, but yeah, as a user with tag editing privileges, you can do it yourself, too.

Comment: It looks like @Mike has taken care of the rest of these questions, so I'm gonna call this one status-completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abracadabra!

[word-square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-square)

Feel free to go and tag all the other word-square questions with this tag, and also to write a tag wiki description for it.

Comment: Though the questions linked in the OP are taken care of, there are many more to go